# Type "x" used after "{" must be a markup extension. Error Code 0x09c6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Getting this weird error while building my solution in one of my user control which has a data template binded to a Model class.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyApp.View.MyMainUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:model="using:MyApp.Model.Entity"
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" x:DataType="model:SomeClass" >
        <local:MyUserControl MySomeClass={x:Bind} />
         </DataTemplate>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The fun part is , If I replace the "MyUserControl" with a textblock , the solution builds fine. And immediately I replace the textblock back with the "MyUserControl" and it builds successfully.
I rebuild again , and it fails with the same error . Any lights on this issue why is it happening?

Is this error "Type "x" used after "{" must be a markup extension" is a random XAML error or a sepcific bug ? On what scenarios could I expect an error. There are no syntax errors if I may remind you guys.
And declaration code of MyUserControl ,

```
 <UserControl
x:Class="MyApp.View.MyUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">`
```

`

using Visual Studio 19 , version 16.3.8

Comment: Did you try deleting your `bin` and `obj` directory?

Comment: tried this  @iam.Carrot , did not work. still getting the same error

Comment: Can you add code to show your `usercontrol` and your `<Page>` tag code. I think I have it figured out

Comment: @iam.Carrot i dont have a <Page>, instead its a UserControl.

Comment: What I mean is the `<Page>` tag of the page where you've used the `<DataTemplate>`. And the declaration xaml of the user control

Comment: its a UserControl inside the datatemplate which is inside a UserControl, I have updated the code , can u infer from that ?

Comment: you're missing a xmlns reference try to replace 

`<MyUserControl MySomeClass={x:Bind} />` 

with
`<local:MyUserControl MySomeClass={x:Bind} />`

Comment: yes @iam.Carrot ,I used <local:MyUserControl>, still i am getting the error , do u know what exactly does this error mean ? I am  not even able to debug

Comment: can you put up a sample code base on github? I'll be able to reproduce it and quickly close this. This seems to be an interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the `{x:Bind}` in quotation marks:

```xml
        <local:MyUserControl MySomeClass="{x:Bind}" />
```